# One to the power of i with two different results.

Tags: complex-numbers

- We can write $1$ in polar form as $1=e^{ik2\pi}$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. If we then take both sides to the power $i$ we arrive at
  $$1^i=e^{-k2\pi},\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
  This looks indeed strange that $1^i$ would be many different numbers. But this do not worry me as much as the final result.
- Another approach of taking a number, say $a$, to a complex power is to write it as $a=e^{\ln(a)}$ and then making use of Euler's formula. Using this for $1$ we get $1=e^{\ln(1)}$. We take both sides to the power of $i$
  $$1^i=e^{i\ln(1)}=\cos[\ln(1)]+i\sin[\ln(1)]=1.$$
  Here we see that $1^i=1$, which is fine. But putting this together we get the statement that I do not agree with $$1=e^{-k2\pi},\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Where did it go wrong and why?

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has infinitely many logarithms. The logarithms of $1$ are $2k\pi i,\; k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and the corresponding values of $1^i$ are $e^{-2k\pi}$. Nothing wrong with that. Just be aware that $(a^b)^c = a^{b\cdot c}$ does not in general hold for specific values of the powers.

Comment: One can define a principal value among those infinite logarithms to salvage some some sense of uniqueness, but at the expense of some properties of $\log$ (to say the least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of looking at the problem is to recognize that $a^n$ for $n$ an integer is always unambiguously defined, but when the exponent is not an integer, the logarithm must be called in, either explicitly or implicitly. And the logarithm can not be defined as a (single-valued) function throughout the space of nonzero complex numbers. So, since there will always be many possible values (occasionally, one of these is clearly preferable) of the logarithm, there will always be many possible values of $a^b$. Your conceptual difficulty is the same as what occurs when we use one of the possible square roots of a number at one time and the other at another time, and get the falsity $1=-1$.

Comment: Succinctly put. I will state for the benefit of OP that the reason you don't see this for integral powers is the following. Generally, if $w$ is one particular value of $\log z$, then all of the others are exactly $w + 2k\pi i$ for integral $k$ ($k=0$ yields the particular value cited). Thus, for integral $n$, the possible values of $z^n$ are $e^{n\cdot(w + 2k\pi i)} = e^{nw}\cdot e^{2nk\pi i} = e^{nw}$ since $e^{2nk\pi i}=1$ for all integral $k$. That is, there is only one value of $z^n$. This *only* happens for integral $n$.

Comment: @MPW, that’s exactly right, but what I had in mind was another (and maybe worse) argument, namely that exponentiation with integer exponent is not an analytic operation, but purely algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer said in the comments, the issue is with the statement at the beginning that

$$1^i = (e^{ik2\pi})^i \neq e^{(ik2\pi \cdot i)}$$

To compute an exponential with complex numbers, you should define

$$a^b = \exp(b \log a)$$

where we should in principle be aware of which branch of the logarithm we are taking.

Given the above, we find that

$$1^i = \exp(i \log 1) = \exp(i \cdot 0) = 1$$

as you determined already.